# JQuery on multiple events

Tags: jquery

I know how to attach a function to an event or even to multiple events, I use the code like this:

```
$(document).off('types_loaded').on('types_loaded',function(e,types){
    display_types(types);
});
```

And somewhere else I do this:

```
$(document).trigger('types_loaded',types);
```

The variable types is loaded from an ajax call.

Everything works fine, but I don't know how to wait for two or more events, something like this:

```
$(document).on('types_loaded' **AND** 'other_loaded',function(e,types,other){
    display_types(types);
    display_other(other);
});
```

And variables **types** and **other** comming from two different ajax calls. I am studing the **when** option, or are there any other way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Since the enumeration on `jQuery.on`'s first attribute works like an `OR` condition (it will fire when any of the events happens), you can transform that behaviour to `AND` by keeping track of what event had happened, like this:

```js
window.eventHappened = {};
$(document).on('types_loaded other_loaded',function(e){
  console.log(e.type);
  window.eventHappened[ e.type ] = 1;
  if (typeof window.eventHappened['types_loaded'] != 'undefined' && typeof window.eventHappened['other_loaded'] != 'undefined')
  {
    // both happened
    console.log('both happened');
  }
});

$(document).trigger('other_loaded');
$(document).trigger('types_loaded');
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I understand, the first parameter **e** has a type property with the name of the event that fires the event, right? If this is true, it's easy to fire a function on any event and other function when both events are done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly, you get it perfectly, that is the case!

Answer (score 2):

If your functions that make the AJAX calls return promises, you can use `$.when`:

```
 function getTypes() {
    return $.ajax( // etc. )
}

function getOther() {
    return $.ajax( // etc. )
}

$.when(getTypes(), getOther()).done(function (typesResult, otherResult) {
    // Both calls have completed
});
```

If you need more control and want to create your own promise, you can manually resolve/reject it when the AJAX response comes back:

```
function getTypes() {
    // This deferred object will return a promise immediately at the bottom of 
    // this function

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax( // etc. )
        .done(function(data) {
            dfd.resolve(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            dfd.reject('Error');
        });

    // This promise returns to the caller immediately

    return dfd.promise();
  }

function getOther() {
    // Same as above
}

$.when(getTypes(), getOther()).done(function (typesResult, otherResult) {
    // Both calls have completed
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the concept is clear but the part that says _Make the AJAX call_ is a little unclear but I'm studying the manual.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the example with more details.